# Hidden MKMapView is somehow receiving touches when scrolling UITableview that is on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a `UIViewController` that uses a `segmentedControl` to switch between a `MKMapView` and a `UITableView` controller. The map shows some locations, then switching to list will show those in list form.

When toggling the `segmentedControl` it will show the corresponding view and hide the other.

The extremely strange issue I am having is, when showing the `tableView` and scrolling down, it sometimes stops scrolling and I can just swipe my finger up and down and the `tableView` does not move. However, I then switch to the map, and it has moved to another location. So I am realizing that somehow when scrolling my hidden `mapView` is receiving those touches.

How is this possible? And is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was a custom callout. When that was open on the map, and I toggled the map hidden, and showed the `tableView`, somehow that callout was still receiving touches, which would then scroll the map with it.

Hiding the callout at the same time as the map solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding the view by setting the `hidden` property to `1`, right? iOS treats views with an alpha of below 0.02 as hidden, too. If you're correctly setting it as hidden, the view is not drawn and should not be receiving any touch events - are you sure something else isn't coming into play here?

Have you overridden the `touchesBegan` method of your `MKMapView` to see if the map view is definitely receiving touches when it is hidden?

Perhaps try setting `hidden` to `1` **and** setting the `alpha` property of the view you want hidden to `0`. If the problem persists, there's most definitely something else going on, as a hidden view is not drawn to the screen at all and thus is not forwarded any touch events by the system.

Comment: Yes, I am setting the hidden property to `YES`.  It doesn't start out hidden. The map is shown first, but then you can toggle it hidden. So, it IS drawn but then hidden when you toggle the control. I will check the `touchesBegan` method and see what I get.

Comment: If you're definitely setting `hidden` to `YES`, the view should not be forwarded any touches. There's something else going on there.

Have you tried `bringSubviewToFront:` for the view you want active? Perhaps that may help. Just bring the one you want to receive touches to the front when it's toggled.

Comment: I will give it a try and see if the problem goes away.